# Chi square for comparing more than 2 categories

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test

I did a retrospective study on complications after 2 types of surgery.  My data is catagorised by subtype of complication (bleeding, infection, nerve damage, ...).  Can someone tell me if I can perform a chi square test to prove is there is a difference between the 2 types of surgery on complications, because it wouldn't be a 2x2 cross table , but a larger one.

Comment: Yes you can, but all it could tell you is that they produce different complications differently, not how different or in what way different .  If the types of surgery are indeed different (rather than being identical but with different names), this should be no surprise and such a conclusion is almost inevitable with enough data

Comment: How about logistic regression?